# How to create a dedicated task for background tasks in .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question is in regards to this blog entry. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

All the way at the bottom Jeff mentions he uses a dedicated task to solve this.

I searched on SO and found this solution [Scheduled jobs in ASP.NET website without buying dedicated servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733643/scheduled-jobs-in-asp-net-website-without-buying-dedicated-servers)
I'm not entirely sure if this what Jeff meant. If that is the procedure he meant, I can just close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just reread that, and Jeff could mean anything at all.

If you read all the comments, you'll see that they run against doing this in the ASP.NET code. That's not what it's for. Put background tasks where they belong - in a service, or at worst, a scheduled task.