# How run some function once per day with asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. I'm familiar with other MVC frameworks like Rails and PHP MVC FM.

I need to run inside ASP.NET MVC some function once per day at the same time - how should I do it? I'd like this function to update a database.

In Linux, I can just put the URL to the server that Cron accesses once a day, but I don't know the best way to do it in Windows.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. Create a scheduled task on your server to manage it.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a service, or something to that effect. Look into windows task scheduler, or windows services.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that the worker process that would start the task lives at the requested time. Maybe it is just to be recycled? So I agree to asawyer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheduled jobs in ASP.NET website without buying dedicated servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733643/scheduled-jobs-in-asp-net-website-without-buying-dedicated-servers)

Comment: If you are running your website from a hosting provider you will not be able to use a service or a scheduled task, but using the ASP.NET cache as described in the linked answer will allow you to schedule tasks.

Comment: @Martin Liversage Liversage: Very cool! I'm not too familiar with that approach (haven't had the need to do it before), but I consider myself schooled. :P

Comment: @MartinLiversage That sounds very unreliable. What if no one visits the website for a day? How does your task run now?

Comment: @Yosef If it's a database maintence task use the sql agent job scheduler.

Comment: I have a lot of code that some of him update database, sql agent job scheduler not for that

Comment: I agree with @asawyer. If you need this reliably executed, you should be creating a scheduled task as bending ASP.NET cache to do this is not the right tool, in this case.  You *can* use this approach if it is something that *should* be executed before someone visits the site, but the timing is not critical (updating a QOTD, for instance). But if you are trying to execute a process that is time-sensitive (delivery of reports, external data processing, a myriad of other scenarios) stick to the scheduled task.

Comment: This helped me to accomplish similar task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733643/scheduled-jobs-in-asp-net-website-without-buying-dedicated-servers

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add two AppSettings to the web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  .
  <add key="TimerStartTime" value="09:00:00 PM"/>
  <add key="TimerIntervalInMilliseconds" value="3000000"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then, in the Global.asax.cs file modify and add:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
// Added the following for the timer related code
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace TestVSOnline01
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        // Added this class visible variable to hold the timer interval so it's not gotten from the
        // web.config file on each Elapsed event of the timer
        private static double TimerIntervalInMilliseconds =
            Convert.ToDouble(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerIntervalInMilliseconds"]);

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            // Added the following within the Application_Start() procedure:
            // *******************************************************************************************
            // The values used in this example will cause your processes to run sometime
            // between 09:00:00 PM and 09:05:00 PM, with the timer Elapsed event being raised
            // every 300000ms (5 minutes)
            //
            // The following AppSettings were added to Web.config:
            //    TimerStartTime
            //    TimerIntervalInMilliseconds
            // You can use a simple text editor to change your start time and/or timer interval without
            // having to modify your code, recompile, and republish it. 
            //
            // The shorter the interval, then smaller the time window in which the processes will run, but
            // the more frequently all of this code and event firing is happening. But you could set the
            // interval to 1000ms and have you events run right at the time specified.
            //
            // !!! NOTE: The web.config file is not designed for constant updates. When an ASP.NET
            // !!! application launches a watch is put on the web.config file. ASP.NET will detect if the
            // !!! web.config changes while the application is running. When ASP.NET detects a change it
            // !!! will spin up a new version of the application with the new settings in effect. Any in
            // !!! process information, such as data kept in Session, Application, and Cache will be lost
            // !!! (assuming session state is InProc and not using a state server or database).
            // !!! (Source: http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx)
            //
            // *******************************************************************************************

            // The Debug.WriteLine calls are for watching the progress in the Output Window
            // in Visual Studio - Remove or comment out if you like

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat("Application_Start Called: ", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

            // This will raise the Elapsed event every 'x' millisceonds (whatever you set in the
            // Web.Config file for the added TimerIntervalInMilliseconds AppSetting
            Timer timer = new Timer(TimerIntervalInMilliseconds);

            timer.Enabled = true;

            // Setup Event Handler for Timer Elapsed Event
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

            timer.Start();
        }

        // Added the following procedure:
        static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the TimerStartTime web.config value
            DateTime MyScheduledRunTime = DateTime.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerStartTime"]);

            // Get the current system time
            DateTime CurrentSystemTime = DateTime.Now;

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat("Timer Event Handler Called: ", CurrentSystemTime.ToString()));

            // This makes sure your code will only run once within the time frame of (Start Time) to
            // (Start Time+Interval). The timer's interval and this (Start Time+Interval) must stay in sync
            // or your code may not run, could run once, or may run multiple times per day.
            DateTime LatestRunTime = MyScheduledRunTime.AddMilliseconds(TimerIntervalInMilliseconds);

            // If within the (Start Time) to (Start Time+Interval) time frame - run the processes
            if ((CurrentSystemTime.CompareTo(MyScheduledRunTime) >= 0) && (CurrentSystemTime.CompareTo(LatestRunTime) <= 0))
            {                
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Concat("Timer Event Handling MyScheduledRunTime Actions: ", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                // RUN YOUR PROCESSES HERE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cleaned up, it's pretty simple. The code below is just a simplified version of what you need to add to the Global.asax.cs file (don't forget the add the `web.config` appsettings still):

```
// Added the following for the timer related code
using System.Diagnostics; // Can remove this reference if you remove all the Debug.Writeline entries
using System.Timers;
using System.Web.Configuration;

// Add the following to the top of the main class, outside of any subroutines:
private static double TimerIntervalInMilliseconds = Convert.ToDouble(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerIntervalInMilliseconds"]);

// Add the following to the end of the Application_Start() subroutine:
Timer timer = new Timer(TimerIntervalInMilliseconds);
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Start();

// Added the following procedure:
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {    
        DateTime MyScheduledRunTime = DateTime.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerStartTime"]);
        DateTime CurrentSystemTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime LatestRunTime = MyScheduledRunTime.AddMilliseconds(TimerIntervalInMilliseconds);
        if ((CurrentSystemTime.CompareTo(MyScheduledRunTime) >= 0) && (CurrentSystemTime.CompareTo(LatestRunTime) <= 0))
        {                
            // RUN YOUR PROCESSES HERE
        }
    }
```